# How do I get nonvirtualized DPI in a winforms app despite (usually) needing virtualization

Tags: c#, dpi

Our team maintains a legacy application written in C# using WinForms. Because the application does not self-handle DPI changes, we currently run DPI Unaware in our app manifest.

This allows Windows to handle DPI scaling for us, which works 99% of the time. However, there are 3rd party components in our application (closed source) such as the "Microsoft Report Viewer".

This viewer displays reports that occasionally need dynamic (programmatic) content to be inserted at runtime.

Unfortunately, running DPI Unaware means code such as graphics.DpiX always returns the virtualized value ("96"), despite running a monitor at a DPI such as 192.

To the best of my knowledge, even Windows libraries will return the virtualized "96" value rather than the true DPI. Calls to functions such as GetDpiForWindow() still give the virtualized value.

Because WinForms scales reasonably well when Windows itself handles the scaling for us, we would like to keep the app DPI Unaware. Even so, we would need to have access to the TRUE DPI, so our team can make dynamic adjustments in runtime code.

What would be the correct way to accomplish this?